# Class diagram - Android app for dog owners

Tags: android, uml, class-diagram

I am struggling how to model the class diagram. I am confused with bindings. Users can create a new dog. When the user is removed also reminders, dogs should be deleted. Isnt it composition? Memories are related to dogs, they should be deleted when the dog is deleted too. Could you help with the bindings?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are absolutely right with your assumption. A composite aggregation is shown by a filled diamond towards the aggregating class. And it's intended use is like you need it (forgot to include multiplicities):

[image]

As a side note:

- your FireBaseApplication seems to be way off. There shouldn't be any class specific methods like `removeDogCascade` but only a `removeCascaded` where you can supply a class that has aggregate relations.
- between `User` and `Dog` you should use a role name `owner` towards `User` to identify the dog's owner, rather than having a `String` property with the user's name (or whatever that might contain)
- Similarly between `Dog` and `Memory`

Comment: If I understand correctly I should change it everything to a composite aggregation. I will remove the Firebase Application. I assume I designed wrongly because in the code I use userId inside DogModel. I use NoSQL database and I get all dogs of user. I could add a list of dogs to the user but it won't capture reality.

Comment: No. Your aggregations are just fine. The role names can later be mapped to some kind of foreign key.

Comment: Then I should change the binding between User and Reminder to aggregation, shouldn't I?

Comment: If the Reminder has a lifetime on it's own you can do so. A shared aggregation however is rather pointless ("Precise semantics of shared aggregation varies by application area and modeler.") and can well be represented by a simple association.

Comment: Reminders live independetly (can be changed, removed, created..)until the user is deleted. Then they have to be deleted too. I guess it should a shared aggregation. I found a useful link http://www.cems.uwe.ac.uk/~jsa/UMLJavaShortCourse09/CGOutput/Unit4/unit4(0809)/page_15.htm

Comment: That actually means their lifetime is bound to the user and you should use a composite aggregation instead.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131634/discussion-between-user3637775-and-thomas-kilian).